# The Problem with UIGraphicsPopContext() ...?

Tags: iphone, ios4

I spent my whole night to solve that problem but i still mad with that

here the picture about my code:
http://i284.photobucket.com/albums/ll15/hisinhvien/Screenshot2011-03-03at112716PM.png
(Sorry b/s new user cant post an image)

first, I overrided the "drawRect" of my "@interface Component : UIView" then i put some code into it to test the push and pop graphic context but it didn't work
follow the picture: the first I chose the green color then I pushed the context and chose the blue color then drawn a rect after that i POPED the context out but the last rect still be blue... ?

here is my source code : http://www.mediafire.com/?aakgqw92flc808o
It's very simple but got wrong... @@

Answer (score 5):

Use [CGContextSaveGState](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html%23//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextSaveGState) and [CGContextRestoreGState](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000950-CH1g-F17035).

Documentation quote about what's saved:

**Discussion**

Each graphics context maintains a stack of graphics states. Note that not all aspects of the current drawing environment are elements of the graphics state. For example, the current path is not considered part of the graphics state and is therefore not saved when you call the CGContextSaveGState function. The graphics state parameters that are saved are:

- CTM (current transformation matrix)
- clip region
- image interpolation quality
- line width
- line join
- miter limit
- line cap
- line dash
- flatness
- should anti-alias
- rendering intent
- fill color space
- stroke color space
- fill color
- stroke color
- alpha value
- font
- font size
- character spacing
- text drawing mode
- shadow parameters
- the pattern phase
- the font smoothing parameter
- blend mode

It's also good thing to save state at the beginning of your drawRect: method and call restore at the end of your drawRect: method. You're not creating your own context here, you're just using already created context and you should preserve it's state. In other words, use it, but leave it as it in the same state at the end.

Comment: P.S. Even if you can't images, you can add code in your question. Simply copy & paste it, select the whole code and click on {} button to mark it as code (= change formatting, make it nicely readable).

Comment: Yeah ! Thanks you so much !
I tried your way and it worked ! but the UIGraphicsPopContext() still bothers me a little that what wrong I made ... or my computer was in trouble ect ... ? B/c I searched a lot about it on google but no one has meet the same condition @_@.

Answer (score 0):

UIGraphicsPushContext allows you to push a different graphics context. You could use it to draw into a bitmap context from inside your drawRect method, for example. It's useful if you want to cache some of your draw calls to an image and then draw that image into your view's context. Pushing a new graphics context is an entirely different thing from pushing your current context's state.

So, to be clear, when drawRect is called, UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() returns your view's context. If you have another context that you want to draw into, you call UIGraphicsPushContext(imageContext). Now UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() returns your other context, which means any drawing code you have that always draws into the current context will be drawing into imageContext in this case. When you call UIGraphicsPopContext(), UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() will return your view's context once again.